# How to use update source trigger on Wpf Combobox which is editable?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox, updatesourcetrigger

I have a combo box (in my wpf-mvvm app). I have set `IsEditable = true`. But the "property changed  event" is getting fired when I start typing.

How can I set `UpdateSourceTrigger = Propertychanged` here ?

Also..I need to call a validation function if user has entered new value ( i mean other than those available in list ..using edit functionality).

Any help will be appreciated.

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path = PlanTypeBasedContractNumberList }" Width="90" IsEditable="True"  
SelectedValue="{Binding GeneralCharacteristicsDataContext.ContractNumber.Value}">
                            </ComboBox>
```

Comment: How did you bind the ComboBox? Please post some code...

Comment: I have updated the querstion with code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In an editable `ComboBox`, the `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue` properties refer to the `Popup` items, not the editable item.  Once you start typing, the `SelectedItem` becomes "unselected" and that's why the event fires.

To bind to the value of the `TextBox` of the `ComboBox`, use the `Text` property:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" Text="{Binding Path=..., UpdateSourceTrigger=...}">
```

Comment: what you mean by "Text box of combobox" ? The textbox in item template ? Could you give me a sample code ?

Comment: When you use `IsEditable` with `ComboBox`, you get a composite control that contains a `Popup` and a `TextBox` as a result of the `ControlTemplate`.  It's the thing you type into.  The sample code I gave is all you need.

Comment: But in the above sample, where is the SelectedValue/SelectedItem ?...I mean, when i select another item from the list..Text will not be set & Only Selecteditem/value will be set, right ?

Comment: If an item is selected from the `Popup`, `Text` will contain its text, just like you see on the screen.

Comment: I'm catching a property changed event....on change of this selected item..i have to do some actions. With the above code..my text's porperty chnge is called...but not on already existing list's selected value change

Comment: Then what you want is the code you presented.  See the first section of my answer.